# JavaScript looping through JSON with jQuery and converting yyyy-mm-dd to timestamp, adding to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

I've written the code below that fetches JSON from a GET route.  It's fairly simple, however, when I load the page and check the console it's logging `0` for `records` and logging `NaN` for `(total_inforce - total_submit) / records;`

What could be the problem here?  I've went through and verified that the values being added are correct.

```
var total_submit = 0;
var total_inforce = 0;  
var records = 0;        

$.ajax({
    url: '/portal/data',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, value) {
            if(value.inforce_date_c != null && value.submitted_date_c != null) {
                var inforce_date = value.inforce_date_c;
                var submit_date = value.submitted_date_c;

                total_inforce += new Date(inforce_date).getTime() / 1000;
                total_submit += new Date(submit_date).getTime() / 1000;
                records += 1;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Snippet that calculates final result:

`console.log((total_inforce - total_submit) / records);`

Here is some example of the JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "inforce_date_c": "2014-05-02",
        "submitted_date_c": "2014-03-19"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you supply the JSON?

Comment: Note that both Firefox and Chrome will interpret dates that look like that (yyyy-mm-dd) as UTC and not the local time zone.

Comment: Can you also post the code doing the calculation?

Comment: Wheere do you have the console.log?

Comment: `console.log` isn't in there for readability.  I placed them all over though.

Comment: @Pointy you can add e.g. `T00:00:00+01:00` where the `+01:00` the timezone (calculated from `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`, and then _Date_ should interpret it correctly.

Comment: Is the console.log inside the "success" function?

Comment: @Josep I had some in and some out.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this could be a problem with the fact that you are making an aSync call and you are probably logging the values immediately after you make the `get` call, which is before the `success` function gets executed.

Also, try replacing this line:

```
if(value.inforce_date_c != null && value.submitted_date_c != null) {
```

With this:

```
if(value.inforce_date_c !== undefined && value.submitted_date_c !== undefined) {
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I can only think of 2 possible issues:

1) You are already getting the dates as dates, therefore you don't need to do `new Date(...)`

2) You are getting wrong format values where you expect to get "YYYY-MM-DD", if the problem is the second case, try with this code (but first, make sure that the dates that you are receiving are strings and not dates):

```
  function parseMyDate(date){
      var dSplit = date.split("-");
      if(dSplit.length!=3)
        return null;
      var year = pareseInt(dSplit[0]);
      var month = pareseInt(dSplit[1]);
      var day = pareseInt(dSplit[2]);

      if(isNaN(year) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(day))
        return null;

      return new Date(year, month, day);
  }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/portal/data',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                if(value.inforce_date_c !== undefined && value.submitted_date_c !== undefined) {
                    var tinforce = parseMyDate(value.inforce_date_c);
                    var tsubmit = parseMyDate(value.submitted_date_c);
                    if(tinforce!==null && tsubmit!==null){
                          total_inforce += tinforce.getTime()/1000;
                          total_submit += tsubmit.getTime()/1000;
                          records++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still returned `NaN` and logged many 0s in the console.  I'm assuming that's because it included values that were `null`.

Comment: When I put `console.log(new Date(inforce_date).getTime() / 1000);` below `var submit_date = ...` it returns the timestamps properly.  Not sure if that helps.  It seems like it just isn't adding.

Comment: @asgwar12 are you checking the value of `records` **inside** or **outside** the "success" handler?  If outside, then that's your problem.

Comment: @Josep comparing with `!= null` is exactly like comparing being not equal to either `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  I declare the variable outside, add to in in the loop, end the loop, log it outside.

Comment: I just made an update, I haven't tested the code, but I guess that it should work

Comment: I can only think of 2 possible issues:

1) You are already getting the dates as dates, therefore you don't need to do new Date(...)

2) You are getting wrong format values where you expect to get "YYYY-MM-DD", if the problem is the second case, try with the code of my updated answer